# PHP Not catching ajax request

Tags: php, jquery

I am having request like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#novaProfaktura").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../Pages/Program.php",
          data: { action: "testing" },
          success: function()
          {
              alert("Ajax done"); //Testing purpose
          }
        });
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

And then in my body I have php like this:

```
<div id="Content">
    <?php
    echo("Php running <br>");
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        echo("Post running <br>");
        if($_POST['action'] = "testing")
        {
            echo("Action running <br>");
        }
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

What I am getting from this is `alert message` so I assume ajax is set up properly and getting `Php running` but it doesn't pass `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`

As you can see jQuery code is running on div click.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have used `function(data)` and it seems to work BUT it doesn't return only `echoed` data but WHOLE page with echo. I used `document.write()` and it rewrite whole page but how to get particular echo value?

Comment: How have you determined that the `if` statement isn't being hit? You're not doing anything with the returned HTML in the AJAX call...?

Comment: Not the answer, but `if($_POST['action'] = "testing")` should be `if($_POST['action'] == "testing")`

Comment: You need a parameter in `success: function(data)` Then you can look into `data` for the response from the PHP on the server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well I did echo. Isn't that supposed to print it just like with first echo?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am trying with `function(data)` but it returns me code of whole page but now WITH echoed data

Comment: @AleksaRistic it will echo to the response which is received by the AJAX request, but then you need to work with that in your JS which is the step you are missing out on.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan look at edited question please

Comment: "BUT it doesn't return only echoed data but WHOLE page with echo"...you should ideally be sending your AJAX request to a separate PHP script which only does the processing required for that request. Otherwise yes you're liable to get other bits of output in there.

Comment: It's echoing the whole page as that's what you're returning. You need to separate the logic which is executed by the AJAX request to its own page, or put it in an `if` statement which excludes the rest of the page.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you all. Using `function(data)` and separating `php` file with function worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this was to instead of this:

```
success: function()
{
    alert("Ajax done"); //Testing purpose
}
```

use this:

```
success: function(data)
{
    alert("Ajax done"); //Testing purpose
    document.getDocumentById('emptyDiv').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Now as data you are getting all HTML text from document you are running function from so instead of `url: "../Pages/Program.php"` I used separated file `url: "../Php/Testing.php"` and inside that file I have
 only this code:

```
<?php
    echo("Testing");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$_POST['action'] = "testing"
```

This is variable assignment

```
$_POST['action'] == "testing"
```

This is comparison. You want this.

```
$_POST['action'] === "testing"
```

This is better because it's type matching too, it must be a string.

Comment: this should have been posted as a comment

Comment: Stil not solving problem

Comment: This is true but it's not the main / only issue